# Finding sums and max.min for an array/matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I have this array pro-matrix.

```
var array =[[1,2,3,4],
            [2,3,4,5],
            [6,5,4,3],
            [4,3,2,1]];
```

I'm trying to find the sum for the whole array as well as each line. This is my function for finding the total sum but it's returning anything.

```
        function sumArray(array) {
          for (
            var
              index = 0,              
              length = array.length,  
              sum = 0;                
              index < length;        
              sum += array[index++]   
          );
          return sum;
        }
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2, 1]],
    sums = array.map(function (a) {
        return a.reduce(sum);
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sums, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('total: ' + sums.reduce(sum));
```

ES6

```js
var add = (a, b) => a + b,
    array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2, 1]],
    sums = array.map(a => a.reduce(add));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sums, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('total: ' + sums.reduce(add));
```

Comment: you can make `(a, b) => a + b` as a variable `var sum = (a, b) => a + b` and then pass to `reduce`

Comment: @isvforall, i've never done something in es6 before.

Comment: it's just syntactic sugar, nothing complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution in one line with `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
var array =[[1,2,3,4],
            [2,3,4,5],
            [6,5,4,3],
            [4,3,2,1]];

var sum = 0;

array.forEach(a => a.forEach(b => sum+=b));

document.write(sum);
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach

Answer (score 1):

Variables intstantiated in the `for`-loop are not accessible outside this loop. Your code should be this:

```
function sumArray(array) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var index = 0;                
          index < array.length;        
          sum += array[index++]   
      );
      return sum;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what we are looking for.  This returns the same as OP's code when called as `sumArray(array)`  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/hu9xqpee/

Comment: You're right. I don't know what OP was asking for then. His code does return a value: the sum of the first items of every array. I am starting to doubt my knowledge on javascript variable scopes now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.concat.apply() to flatten your array and then reduce it to compute sum of all elements:

```
var sum = [].concat.apply([], array).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

console.log(sum); // 52
```

If you can use ES6 syntax it could be even more elegant using arrow function and spread operator:

```
[].concat(...array).reduce((a, b) => a + b); // 52
```

Answer (score 0):

You have arrays in array, so you can use your function to each row this way:

```
for (var i = 0, total_sum = 0; i < array.length; total_sum += sumArray(array[i++]));
console.log(total_sum);
```

It's not the best way writing readable code in javascript, but I like it =)

Answer (score 0):

The array is an array of four arrays with four elements elements each. You want to find the sum of each line and the sum of all lines.

How about this?

```
function sumArray( array ) {
    var lineTotals = [];
    var grandTotal = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        lineTotals.push( 0 );
        for ( var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++ ) {
        lineTotals[ i ] += array[ i ][ j ];
    }
    grandTotal += lineTotals[ i ];
    }
    return grandTotal;
}
```